# MongoDB Atlas connecting to Compass GUI but not to the " application "

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern, mongodb-atlas

Using the connecting string , I have successfully connected to Compass

but to connect the application which I'm developing its not connecting , what may be the problem ? I'm banging my head to resolve this issue , no solution in google is helping me out .

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added the `mern` and `mongoose` tags, follow the below sample code to connect to the MongoDB Atlas using mongoose.

**Example:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectionString = <YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING>

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

mongoose
    .connect(connectionString).then()
    .then(() => {
      app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port + `\n http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ,  But it didn't work  because the problem is somewhere with the Firewall , the same code I ran on another pc , it was working . @Rukshana Jayasekara